# How to show result?

Tags: java

I just made this java code to convert decimal to roman. But the result dont show up. Any workaround?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Roman {
    private static String answer;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num, m;
        num = input.nextInt();
        String[] rom = {"m", "cm", "d", "cd", "c", "xc", "l", "xl", "x", "ix", "v", "iv", "i"};
        int[] numerals = {1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1};
        for (int i=0; i<numerals.length; i++){
            m = num/numerals[i];
            num = num%numerals[i];
            answer = new String(new char[m]).replace("\0", rom[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hint: you're reassigning `answer` on every iteration of your loop. You're printing it at the end - so only the *last* numeral will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the String answer step-by-step by concatenating the single Strings of the Roman figures.
Therefore you need to look, if `num/numerals[i]` is not zero.

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<numerals.length; i++){
   if(num/numerals[i] != 0) {
     answer = answer.concat(rom[i]);
   }
   num = num%numerals[i];
}
```

I hope, this helps :)